# Not able to access views in laravel 5 from url

Tags: laravel-5

I have followed these steps to remove index.php from url. I am working on laravel 5 and i have followed the insrtuection to remove index.php and public from url..but after i am not able to access my views folder and pages using url.Only main link like www.art.local is working www.art.local/index/register this is not working.
         Please Help

```
        Renaming the server.php to index.php (no modifications)
        Copy the .htaccess from public 
        Changing .htaccess it a bit as follows for statics:

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !      (\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
       RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: after that i have used this code:

Comment: I changed /Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php/asset() function as follows:

function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
}

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5, by default, you don't need to include `index` in your URL. For example, lets say we have this route:

```
Route::get('register', function () {
    return 'Hello world';
}
```

So if you try to go to `localhost/register`, You'll get *Hello World* output.

---

**Update 1:**

IIR, If you're using services like "WampServer" to run your server, you should enable `module_rewrite` in your Apache and then restart it. For more informatiom, please see this answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

Comment: Did you revert your changes? And please provide your routes.php file.

Comment: My Route.php I am able to acces this all but after using index.php in url..but i dont want index.php in url                                                                     Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  
    Route::post('postrequest', array('as' => 'postrequest', 'uses' => 'AdminController@login', function() {
    
}));
Route::get('register', function () {
    return 'Hello world';
});  });

Comment: @yogeswari Which OS you're running your server? Are you using a Server Service like WampServer? I need more information to help you

Comment: I am using Linux.and LAMP Server

Comment: Go to your Apache, and enable `module_rewrite` and everything should work.

Comment: I have enabled  module_rewrite.Still facing same problem :(

Comment: please run `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: pls help not able to remove index.php from laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

To move your site main url from public in windows you should make a vitual host.to do this first open

1.Open the XAMPP control panel application and stop Apache. Be aware that late Windows machines might run it as a service, so check the box to the left of the Apache module.

2.Navigate to C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra or wherever your XAMPP files are located.

3.Open the file named httpd-vhosts.conf with a text editor.

4.Around line 19 find # NameVirtualHost *:80 and uncomment or remove the hash.

At the very bottom of the file paste the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" # change this line with your htdocs folder
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

6. Now you can copy and paste the code above below to add your Virtual Host directories. For example I’m working on a site called Eatery Engine so the following snippet will allow me to work with sub-domains on my local install:

   ```
   <VirtualHost eateryengine.dev>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel-projcet/public"#path to your project #in laravel project be sure to set path to public folder
    ServerName eateryengine.dev
    ServerAlias eateryengine.dev
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/eateryengine">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   7.Next head over to your Windows host file to edit your HOSTS. the file will be located at `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`, where hosts is the file. Open it with notepad.
7. Look for

`localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost`

9. Add your project name with bottom of this line (This is DNS ADDRESS OF YOUR DOMAIN)

`127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       eateryengine.dev #change to match your Virtual Host.
127.0.0.1       demo.eateryengine.dev #manually add new sub-domains.`

Restart Apache and test everything.

now you can access your site without typing localhost or public in url just type domain name which you have register in httpd-vhosts.conf file

The original article for setting virtual host in windows can be found here http://austin.passy.co/2012/setting-up-virtual-hosts-wordpress-multisite-with-xampp-on-windows-7/

thanks sunny but already i have created virtual host..and working in linux... Route::get('/','UserController@index');  Route::get('/user','UserController@myaccount');

www.loveart.dev/ then fisrt is working.
www.loveart.dev/user second don't working

Comment: ys i have did that and first page is opening...but if i have to acces ...http://www.weloveart.local/user/register this and in route file   Route::get('user/register','Controller@register');
 Route::resource('user', 'Controller'); this i ma able to get..pls help

Comment: if you want access ...weloveart.local/user/register url and already declare recourse for `/user` url. then to access `/user.register` page register it manually like  `Route::get('user/register','Controller@register');`  For more information on routes see its [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: if You think taht route will effected after moving index.php file then you are wrong. Route will run as it was before moving file.

Comment: yes..but still it s not working.don't how index.php will be removed from url in laravel 5.2

Comment: it must be server config problem check your server detail

Comment: is there mod_rewrite is on or not

Comment: all this issue only for remove index.php or public from url in laravel right. so for that i have better option for you instead moving file and make a .htaccess config you can maKe a virtual host(FOR WINDOWS) for project check my uodated answer.

Comment: does it throw 404 error ?? try to catch it in exception handler

Comment: it gives..The requested URL /user was not found on this server.

Comment: means it doesn't run laravel for this request ??

Comment: did you try to set DirectoryIndex to index.php in virtual host setting ?? because i thing i think system cannot found a default directory index to run

Comment: on server my htaccess file on root but asset not taking public in asset('images/abc.jpg')..pls help